# AJAX HTMLEditor not working on production server but works on dev envt

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-config, html-editor

I am fairly new at this and am having a problem deploying my web site (ASP.net with some AJAX components) and have been going mad trying to find an explanation.

Generally everything works with one exception, the pages that are using the AJAX HTMLEditor are not working when reading / updating / deleting from an MS Access database. I have other AJAX controls on the pages (Such as calendar extender) which appear to be working properly. I also have fiorms with textbox's which all update the database correctly.

I have 2 test environments both running IIS 7 and both work as they should. The Visual Studio2010 development testing also works correctly.

I suspect that the problem lies in the IIS configuration or web.config settings.

Any help would be appreciated, I have been looking for answers for a few days and am fast approaching insanity...

Thanks in advance.

This is the web.config that currently works on my test server using IIS 7.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add name="CI1ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data          Source=|DataDirectory|CI1.mdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="AppCtlConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1AppCtl.mdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="SurveyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1Surveys.mdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
        <add name="LogFileConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1SystemLogs.mdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false"
    enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" >
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="EOWebRuntime" type="EO.Web.Runtime,EO.Web"/>
        </httpModules>
        <httpHandlers>
        </httpHandlers>

        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />

        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <trust level="Full" />
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="CTL_Problem.aspx" />
        <compilation batch="true" batchTimeout="900" debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" explicit="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="15" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <globalization culture="en-AU" enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-AU" />
    </system.web>

    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp>
                <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="index.aspx" />
        </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>

    <location path="Styles/Site.css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="data">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="functions">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
              <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
</configuration>
```

Ok I have done some more exploration and updated my web.config (see below). The behavior now has the page able to read the data (not every time though) and update the database (insert and update) randomly. Seriously weird how the update appears to work on every second attempt.

Anyway here is the new web.config..... Thanks for any help possible.

```
<configuration>    
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="CI1ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="AppCtlConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1AppCtl.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="SurveyConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1Surveys.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    <add name="LogFileConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|CI1SystemLogs.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false">
      <controls>
          <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

      <httpHandlers>
          <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
          <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type= "System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
      </httpHandlers>

      <httpModules>
          <add name="EOWebRuntime" type="EO.Web.Runtime,EO.Web" />
          <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </httpModules>

      <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="UseCookies" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="600" 
        sqlConnectionString="Data Source=tcp:s05.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=DB_25270_blackrobot;User ID=DB_25270_blackrobot_user;Password=itstime2work;Integrated Security=False;" timeout="120">
    </sessionState>

    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <trust level="Full" />
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="CTL_Problem.aspx" />
    <compilation batch="true" batchTimeout="900" debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" explicit="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="15" strict="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <globalization culture="en-AU" enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-AU" />
  </system.web>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="localhost" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
          <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </modules>
      <handlers>
          <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
          <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </handlers>

      <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="cwme.org.au" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?cwme.org.au" />
                      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/Amna/" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="\Amna\{R:0}" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>

      <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
          <add value="default.aspx" />
          <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="Styles/Site.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="data">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="functions">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

ARGH I have found the problem and resolved it. After exhaustive research it turned out to be that the resource allocation on my host was being exhausted. Upgraded the hosting plan, doubled the allocated memory and the problem has been resolved!

$100 more p.a., a lot cheaper than the psycho doc!

Comment: Thank you for explaining what caused the problem (although you solved it yourself)!